# Live Ubuntu 12.04 USB Disc not detected in UEFI

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, uefi

This was not my first time attempting dual boot, but it is for doing this with Windows 8. The troublesome UEFI does not detect my USB stick although I changed the boot order and disabled secure boot. Then I changed to Legacy BIOS, it now detects the USB stick and I can boot into a live session, but it is still useless as Windows 8 needs to boot using UEFI and automatically I have to install Ubuntu as UEFI too, but there is no such option since I am using Legacy BIOS. So I tried to install Ubuntu using Legacy BIOS (thought of switching between UEFI and Legacy BIOS when I want to switch OS), but when I restart, I can't boot into Ubuntu at all, it always states "Please insert removable media and..."...Any possible workaround for this? It is kinda important as I have projects to be done using Ubuntu.

**Note: I am running Acer Aspire V3-571G. Made a Live USB Stick using ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. The Live USB I created was not EFI compatible (i.e. no files/folders in /boot/grub that have "efi" in the name). So I what I did was simply re-creating the Live USB within Ubuntu on another laptop using the Startup Disk Creator utility. Previously, I made the Live USB using Universal USB Installer (did it with Windows) which does not create the "efi" files at all. Now, my Live USB is detected and I just dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 (with secure boot disabled of course).